# Parse SQL to extract column and table names using python

Tags: python, sql

I want to write a code that will extract table and column names from a query that does not have JOIN keyword. Instead, the cartesian join (,) is used as below:

```
SELECT suppliers.supplier_name, subquery1.total_amt
FROM suppliers
,
(SELECT supplier_id, SUM(orders.amount) AS total_amt
FROM orders
GROUP BY supplier_id) subquery1
WHERE subquery1.supplier_id = suppliers.supplier_id;"""
```

I tried using the below code but its not working in python 2.7 as i'm getting the error : Bool object not callable at line 21:

```
    import itertools
    import sqlparse

    from sqlparse.sql import IdentifierList, Identifier
    from sqlparse.tokens import Keyword, DML


    def is_subselect(parsed):
        if not parsed.is_group():
            return False
        for item in parsed.tokens:
            if item.ttype is DML and item.value.upper() == 'SELECT':
                return True
        return False


    def extract_from_part(parsed):
        from_seen = False
        print 'hi'
        for item in parsed.tokens:
            if item.is_group():
                print 'group'
                for x in extract_from_part(item):
                    yield x
            if from_seen:
                print 'from'
                if is_subselect(item):
                    for x in extract_from_part(item):
                        yield x
                elif item.ttype is Keyword and item.value.upper() in ['ORDER', 'GROUP', 'BY', 'HAVING']:
                    from_seen = False
                    StopIteration
                else:
                    yield item
            if item.ttype is Keyword and item.value.upper() == 'FROM':
                from_seen = True


    def extract_table_identifiers(token_stream):
        for item in token_stream:
            if isinstance(item, IdentifierList):
                for identifier in item.get_identifiers():
                    value = identifier.value.replace('"', '').lower()
                    yield value
            elif isinstance(item, Identifier):
                value = item.value.replace('"', '').lower()
                yield value


    def extract_tables(sql):
        # let's handle multiple statements in one sql string
        extracted_tables = []
        statements = (sqlparse.parse(sql))

        for statement in statements:
            # print statement.get_type()
            if statement.get_type() != 'UNKNOWN':
                stream = extract_from_part(statement)
                print stream
                extracted_tables.append(set(list(extract_table_identifiers(stream))))
        return list(itertools.chain(*extracted_tables))


    # strsql = """
    # SELECT p.product_name, inventory.quantity
    # FROM products p join inventory
    # ON p.product_id = inventory.product_id;
    # """

    strsql = """SELECT suppliers.supplier_name, subquery1.total_amt
    FROM suppliers
    ,
     (SELECT supplier_id, SUM(orders.amount) AS total_amt
      FROM orders
      GROUP BY supplier_id) subquery1
    WHERE subquery1.supplier_id = suppliers.supplier_id;"""
    extract_tables(strsql)
```

Error : this is the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "4.py", line 77, in <module>
    extract_tables(strsql)
  File "4.py", line 60, in extract_tables
    extracted_tables.append(set(list(extract_table_identifiers(stream))))
  File "4.py", line 40, in extract_table_identifiers
    for item in token_stream:
  File "4.py", line 21, in extract_from_part
    if item.is_group():
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable
```

Comment: try to fix the indentation on your code

Comment: In python, indentation matters. Your code is not indented, hence it's not testable. Please edit your question and include the proper indentation

Comment: thank you . have added indentation..

Comment: @siete.sh thanks.. have added indents

Comment: @GPhilo thanks.. have added indents

Comment: Can you also post the exact error message (and the traceback) you get? "Line 21" could be anything if formatting is not exactly the same here as in your code

Comment: sure.. @GPhilo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "4.py", line 77, in <module>
    extract_tables(strsql)
  File "4.py", line 60, in extract_tables
    extracted_tables.append(set(list(extract_table_identifiers(stream))))
  File "4.py", line 40, in extract_table_identifiers
    for item in token_stream:
  File "4.py", line 21, in extract_from_part
    if item.is_group():
TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable

Comment: In the question* :) Here it's unreadable (comments do not keep formatting)

Comment: From the traceback it seems `is_group` is actually **not** a function, but a simple `bool` attribute. Try replacing `item.is_group()` with `item.is_group` and see if things improve

Comment: sure @GPhilo.. checking now

Comment: @GPhilo..Excellent friend.. its working now.. many thanks !!!!

Comment: @GPhilo. any pointers for getting the column names?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Gphilo for the answer:

From the traceback it seems is_group is actually not a function, but a simple bool attribute. Try replacing item.is_group() with item.is_group and see if things improve